# Принудительно перерисовать элемент

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте! Есть задача: по мере работы программы, выводить промежуточное состояние в таблицу. Для этого есть примерно такой код:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('table');

function wait(ms)
{
  var time = new Date().getTime();

  while(new Date() - time <= ms){}
}

function run()
{
  for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    var l = document.createElement('tr');
    var e = document.createElement('td');
    e.innerText = String(i);
    l.appendChild(e);
    table.appendChild(l);
    wait(100);
  }
}
```

```html
<table id = table>
</table>
<input type="button" value="run" onclick="run()">
```

При этом, вся информация появляется, но только после завершения работы функции. 
Как сделать так, что бы текст появлялся в тот момент, когда он добавляется в коде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function run()
{
  var table = document.getElementById('table');
  var i = 0;

  add();

  function add() {
    var l = document.createElement('tr');
    var e = document.createElement('td');
    e.innerText = String(i);
    l.appendChild(e);
    table.appendChild(l);
    if (i < 10) {
      i++;
      setTimeout(add, 100);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id = table>
</table>
<input type="button" value="run" onclick="run()">
```